# dynamic colour formatting in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

i have forecast bias values being displayed as percentages and i want to color those values based on certain thresholds like it should be RED if its value greater than 100% and less than -100% and green if between -99% to 99 % so i created a calculated field as

```
If [Forecast Bias] >= 100 THEN "Red"
elseif [Forecast Bias] <= -100 THEN "Red"
elseif [Forecast Bias] > -100 THEN "Green"
END
```

but i am getting some color field as Nul and wrong color on the values.I feel its taking actual values of forecast bias rather than percentage value for comparison.

Comment: Well, it gets exactly the value of [Forecast Bias]. You need to check if the [Forecast Bias] stores absolute or relative values. If it stores absolute values and you want to use the relative value, you need to perform the proper calculation. The only way to get a Null value out of this calculated field is having a Null value for [Forecast Bias].

Comment: The last condition could be expressed more clearly (and efficiently) just as "else".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to separate data rows based on their value for the [Forcecast Bias] field and treat rows separately depending on whether the value of [Forecast Bias] is within your range, then I suggest creating the following calculated field, called, say, "**Bias_in_Range**".

```
abs([Forecast Bias]) < 100
```

This defines a boolean valued dimension calculated field.

You can then place this field on the Color shelf to partition data according to that dimension.
To make the color legend more readable, you can create aliases for the dimension members, True and False in this case, to display labels like "In Range" and "Out of Range" to get readable color legend.

You could replace the hard coded 100 with a parameter, say "**Bias Threshold**", and show the parameter control to allow users to adjust the threshold dynamically.

```
abs([Forecast Bias]) < [Bias Threshold]
```

You will see null values for this field only for data rows that have a null value for [Forecast Bias]. If you don't like that, you have the choice of:

- filtering out nulls,
- fixing the source data to supply the missing field values, or
- adjusting the definition of your calculated field to
  treat the rows with null [Forcecast Bias] as either in range or out of range as you prefer, using a function like isNull() to test for null values

I can't speak to why you may see the wrong color without seeing more info about your data